# Psexec returns an access denied error in a c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, psexec

I'm try trying to launch remote command via psexec tool, it is running successfully in command prompt. However in c#, I get the following output error:

> Access is denied

.
here is my command:

> psexec \servername -u xxxxxxx -p xxxxxxxxxx -h -w "E:\" cmd /C
>   "(dir)" ^> file.txt

here is my c# source:

```
ProcessStartInfo PSI = new ProcessStartInfo();
PSI.FileName = "cmd.exe";
PSI.RedirectStandardInput = true;
PSI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
PSI.RedirectStandardError = true;
PSI.UseShellExecute = false;
PSI.CreateNoWindow = true;
PSI.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
PSI.Arguments = "psexec " + @"\\servername -u xxxxxx -p xxxxxxxxx -h -w "+"\"E:\\\\\" "+"cmd /C " +"\""+"(dir)"+ "\" " +"^> file.txt" ;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().ToString();
error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd().ToString();
```

Comment: Try using psexec switch "-s", this wil run the command under system account, which is the same as running it elevated.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem persists even by adding -s.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't comment yet!

Reading your c# + psexec code, looks like it send 
`psexec \servername -u xxxxxxx -p xxxxxxxxxx -h -w "E:\\" cmd /C "(dir)" ^> file.txt` to command prompt

Shouldn't it be `"psexec " + @"\\servername -u xxxxxx -p xxxxxxxxx -h -w "+"\"E:\\\" "+"cmd /C " +"\""+"(dir)"+ "\" " +"^> file.txt";` to end with `psexec \servername -u xxxxxxx -p xxxxxxxxxx -h -w "E:\" cmd /C "(dir)" ^> file.txt` ?

To test I would suggest you to create an string which will receive those values and then show it, just to be sure is the right command being set.

Another thing is `PSI.UseShellExecute = false;`, I know some command codes must have this set false to work, but I don't know psexec, did you already also tried to set it to true ?

Comment: That's not a problem Luis. For the command, the c# string is written correctly. I have already tested it. For UseShellExecute, when I have changed it to true, the program throws this exception: The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams.

Answer (score 0):

If the server that runs your code is under a domain, then you'll need to add the domain along with the user name.

Therefore, the `-u` flag would be `-u your_domain_name\username`.